# How to integrate EJBs, Spring, Vaadin into an Enterprise Project

Tags: java, spring, ejb, vaadin, ear

I want to create an enterprise project (with EAR packaging) with following modules:

1.) I want to have my Spring beans in the EJB module.
2.) The Vaadin application should be the web module.

Now I have everything in one web project. I have the spring bean configuration in the applicationContext.xml. In the web.xml the application context is configured to get loaded. How can I move the spring beans and the context configuration into the EJB module and deal only with the Vaadin UI in the web module, having the beans automatically injected into my custom components? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [Spring Stuff Vaadin add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/spring-stuff) for help with Spring and Vaadin.

Disclaimer: I'm the author